# Sysprep didn't change the SID

Tags: sysprep, sid

I'm trying to join a 2012 R2 server to a domain controlled by another 2012 R2 server.  The domain is a test domain, but it works.  I joined a different server to this domain.

But I've been trying to create a VM image that could be cloned, and it seemed to work OK.  After boot, the OOBE occurred, asking for a product key.

But when I tried to join the machine to the domain, it failed.  I didn't get the SID duplicate error immediately, but eventually it showed up.  So I ran the PsGetsid64 executable from Microsoft, and sure enough, this server's SID is the same as my domain controller (also created from the same template).

I reran sysprep, and re-imported the VM, and still had the same SID. So I ran sysprep in place, and I still have the same SID.

So clearly I am missing something really basic here.  Someone please instruct the novice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per:  [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824938.aspx) you need to use sysprep with the generalize switch prior to cloning

```
Sysprep /generalize
```

That should fix your issues with the SID.
In case you can't re-run sysprep /generalize and re-clone, I have also had success with adding a machine to the domain, reboot, remove it, then delete the machine account via AD Users and Computers.  Then reboot again and add the machine again.  Sometimes, it takes 2 attempts.

Comment: While you were correctly answering my problem, I was still poking around the net & it finally began to dawn on me that I wasn't checking the generalize box.  So simple to overlook...  Now it changes the SID just fine.  Thx.